# iOS objective-c mapkit Geopoint x and y to latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have GeoJson(WGS84) with Mercator projection coordinates.

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[300815.531,5042213]}
```

When I try to convert these values to long and lat using `MKCoordinateForMapPoint` I'm getting wrong coordinates. What is wrong ?

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPointMake(300815.531, 5042213));
```

The result is : New Coordinates 84.432113, -179.596575

But expected coordinates should be near these values:
+45.51 ,-73.54

Comment: Are you doing this in Swift, Objective-C, or something else?  How are you converting these values exactly?  This question needs more details.

Comment: Using Objective-C and I think for swift would be the same. 

CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate=MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPointMake(300815.531, 5042213));

Comment: Putting this in comments is terrible for reading.  Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30406730/edit) your question and add as much detail as possible.